# How to write URL in browser address bar in AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I am able to open the browser using

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
```

in AutoIt. But not able to get any function to write URL say "google.com" in address bar.

- Can someone help me on it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the address bar to navigate to any page you want.  Alt-d is used by browsers to activate the address bar with the current address selected.  So typing in a new address will replace the old one.

```
Send ( "!dhttp://google.com{ENTER}" )
```

!d is AutoIt syntax for Alt-d

If your browser does not select all text automatically, you can add a Ctrl-A to select it all yourself.

```
Send ( "!d^ahttp://google.com{ENTER}" )
```

Answer (score 2):

To open default browser with google.com:

```
ShellExecute("http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information in order to launch chrome on a page here https://github.com/AOT-DEP-PADI/ChromeLauncher.

With Autoit, just add argume

```vb
Local $chrome_url_start = "http:\\www.google.fr"
Local $chrome_arguments = " --new-window --incognito"

Local $ProgramFilesDir = EnvGet('ProgramFiles(x86)') ; for 64bit Win it will return a valid path.
If not $ProgramFilesDir Then $ProgramFilesDir = @ProgramFilesDir ; for 32bit Win this will "repair" the broken return from above.
Run($ProgramFilesDir & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "&$chrome_url_start&$chrome_arguments)
```

Comment: don't forget the blank space in the variable $chrome_arguments (" --new-window")

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in running the website in IE:

```
#include <IE.au3>
$oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com")
```

To navigate to another page use

```
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?")
```

Check the help file for a lot of IE automation functions.